# Rの{e1071}パッケージの関数 tune.svm() を利用して、C-SVM（ソフトマージンSVM）のパラメータ C をグリッドサーチでチューニングする際のグリッドサーチ結果の作図について

Tags: r, 機械学習

{e1071}パッケージの`tune.svm()`を利用して、C-SVM（ソフトマージンSVM）の C 値のチューニングをグリッドサーチにかけて見つけようとしているのですが、グリッドサーチ結果の図がうまく作成出来ません。
`tune.svm()`を利用してのグリッドサージ結果の作図をご教示して頂けると助かりますm(__)m

<170305追記>
尚、作成したいグラフは以下のような種類のグラフです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`tune.svm()`を含む Wrapper Functions のヘルプ
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.6-8/topics/tune.wrapper

<170317追記>
参考サイト
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/hoxo_m/20110325/p1
https://bi.biopapyrus.net/machine-learning/svm/e1071.html

以下作成中のコードです。

```
#install.packages("kernlab")
#install.packages("e1071")

# expand lib on memory
library( MASS )    # MASS package
library( kernlab ) # use C-SVM function
library( e1071 )   # grid serch of C-SVM

############################
# set Pima data            #
############################
# Pima data expand on memory
data( Pima.tr )
data( Pima.te )

# copy data from Pima data
lstPimaTrain <- list(
  numNoDiabetes = 0,       # 糖尿病未発症人数（0で初期化）
  numDiabetes = 0,         # 糖尿病発症人数（0で初期化）
  glu = Pima.tr$glu, 
  bmi = Pima.tr$bmi, 
  bResult = rep(0, length(Pima.tr$glu)) # 糖尿病か否か？（FALSE:糖尿病でない、TRUE:糖尿病）
)

# Pima.tr$type のデータ（Yes,No）を符号化[encoding]
for ( i in 1:length(Pima.tr$type) ) 
{
  if(Pima.tr$type[i] == "Yes" )
  {
    lstPimaTrain$numDiabetes <- (lstPimaTrain$numDiabetes + 1)
    lstPimaTrain$bResult[i] <- 1
  }
  else if( Pima.tr$type[i] == "No" )
  {
    lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes <- (lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes + 1)
    lstPimaTrain$bResult[i] <- 0
  }
  else{
    # Do Nothing
  }
}

# sort Pima data
lstPimaTrain$glu <- lstPimaTrain$glu[ order(lstPimaTrain$bResult) ]
lstPimaTrain$bmi <- lstPimaTrain$bmi[ order(lstPimaTrain$bResult) ]
lstPimaTrain$bResult <- lstPimaTrain$bResult[ order(lstPimaTrain$bResult) ]

# split data to class C1 and C2
lstPimaTrain_C1 <- list(
  glu = lstPimaTrain$glu[1:lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes], 
  bmi = lstPimaTrain$bmi[1:lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes],
  bResult = rep( 0, lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes ),  # 糖尿病か否か？（FALSE:糖尿病でない、TRUE:糖尿病）
  vec_u = matrix( 0, nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ),
  mat_S = matrix( 0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )
)
lstPimaTrain_C2 <- list(
  glu = lstPimaTrain$glu[(lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes+1):(lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes+lstPimaTrain$numDiabetes)], 
  bmi = lstPimaTrain$bmi[(lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes+1):(lstPimaTrain$numNoDiabetes+lstPimaTrain$numDiabetes)],
  bResult = rep( 1, lstPimaTrain$numDiabetes ),  # 糖尿病か否か？（FALSE:糖尿病でない、TRUE:糖尿病）
  vec_u = matrix( 0, nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ),          # 変数１（glu）の平均値、変数２（BMI）の平均値
  mat_S = matrix( 0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2 )           # 共分散行列
)

# sort class C1,C2 data
lstPimaTrain_C1$glu <- lstPimaTrain_C1$glu[ order(lstPimaTrain_C1$glu) ]
lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi <- lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi[ order(lstPimaTrain_C1$glu) ]
lstPimaTrain_C2$glu <- lstPimaTrain_C2$glu[ order(lstPimaTrain_C2$glu) ]
lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi <- lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi[ order(lstPimaTrain_C2$glu) ]

# release memory
rm( Pima.tr ) 
rm( Pima.te )

# set class C1 data
lstPimaTrain_C1$vec_u <- matrix(       # クラス１（糖尿病発症なし）の平均ベクトル
  c( mean( lstPimaTrain_C1$glu ), mean( lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi ) ), 
  nrow = 2, ncol = 1
)

lstPimaTrain_C1$mat_S[1,1] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C1$glu, lstPimaTrain_C1$glu ) )
lstPimaTrain_C1$mat_S[1,2] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C1$glu, lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi ) )
lstPimaTrain_C1$mat_S[2,1] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi, lstPimaTrain_C1$glu ) )
lstPimaTrain_C1$mat_S[2,2] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi, lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi ) )

# set class C2 data
lstPimaTrain_C2$vec_u <- matrix(       # クラス２（糖尿病発症なし）の平均ベクトル
  c( mean( lstPimaTrain_C2$glu ), mean( lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi ) ), 
  nrow = 2, ncol = 1
)

lstPimaTrain_C2$mat_S[1,1] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C2$glu, lstPimaTrain_C2$glu ) )
lstPimaTrain_C2$mat_S[1,2] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C2$glu, lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi ) )
lstPimaTrain_C2$mat_S[2,1] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi, lstPimaTrain_C2$glu ) )
lstPimaTrain_C2$mat_S[2,2] <- sqrt( var( lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi, lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi ) )


#--------------------------
# normalize Pima data
#--------------------------
lstNormPimaTrain_C1 <- lstPimaTrain_C1
lstNormPimaTrain_C2 <- lstPimaTrain_C2

lstNormPimaTrain_C1$glu <- scale( lstNormPimaTrain_C1$glu )
lstNormPimaTrain_C1$bmi <- scale( lstNormPimaTrain_C1$bmi )
lstNormPimaTrain_C2$glu <- scale( lstNormPimaTrain_C2$glu )
lstNormPimaTrain_C2$bmi <- scale( lstNormPimaTrain_C2$bmi )

############################
# C-SVM                    #
############################
# SVM用のデータ作成
dat_CsvmForm <- c( lstNormPimaTrain_C1$bResult, lstNormPimaTrain_C2$bResult)
df_CsvmData <- data.frame( 
  glu = c( lstNormPimaTrain_C1$glu, lstNormPimaTrain_C2$glu ),
  bmi = c( lstNormPimaTrain_C1$bmi, lstNormPimaTrain_C2$bmi ),
  bResult = dat_CsvmForm
)

#----------------------------
# C-SVMモデル構築
#----------------------------
result <- ksvm(
  dat_CsvmForm ~ ., 
  data = df_CsvmData,       # 
  type = "C-bsvc",           # 分類方法を指定
  kernel = "rbfdot",         # 利用するカーネル関数を指定
  kpar = list(sigma = 0.2),  # カーネル関数のパラメーターを指定
  C = 5,                     # Cパラメーター
  cross = 3,
  prob.model = TRUE          # 予測時に予測確率を出力するためにTRUEに設定
)
print(result)

#----------------------------
# パラメータのチューニング
#----------------------------
# グリッドサーチの範囲
gamma_lim <- 10^( seq(from = -5, to = 5, by = 0.1) ) # 階乗
cost_lim  <- 10^( seq(from = -1, to = 1, by = 0.1) )
```

以下のコードでエラーが発生します。

```
resTune <- tune.svm(
  dat_CsvmForm ~ ., 
  data = df_CsvmData, 
#  gamma = gamma_lim,          # gammaパラメーターをgamma.limの範囲で移動させる 
#  cost = cost_lim,            # costパラメーターをcost.limの範囲で移動させる
  tunecontrol = tune.control( sampling = "cross", cross = 5 )  # 5-cross validation
)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula, data) :     変数 ('glu' に基づく)
>   の長さが異なります

以下コードの続きです。

```
print(resTune)

############################
# set graphics parameters  #
############################
# 軸に関してのデータリスト
lstAxis <- list(                        
  xMin = 0.0, xMax = 1.0,  # x軸の最小値、最大値
  yMin = 0.0, yMax = 1.0,  # y軸の最小値、最大値
  zMin = 0.0, zMax = 1.0,  # z軸の最小値、最大値
  xlim = range( c(0.0, 1.0) ), 
  ylim = range( c(0.0, 1.0) ), 
  zlim = range( c(0.0, 1.0) ),
  mainTitle = "mainTitle", # 図のメインタイトル（図の上）
  subTitle  = "subTitle",  # 図のサブタイトル（図の下）
  xlab      = "x", # x軸の名前
  ylab      = "y", # y軸の名前
  zlab      = "z"  # z軸の名前
)
lstAxis$xMin <- 0
lstAxis$xMax <- 200
lstAxis$yMin <- 0
lstAxis$yMax <- 50
lstAxis$zMin <- 0
lstAxis$zMax <- 1
lstAxis$xlim = range( c(lstAxis$xMin, lstAxis$xMax) )
lstAxis$ylim = range( c(lstAxis$yMin, lstAxis$yMax) )
lstAxis$zlim = range( c(lstAxis$zMin, lstAxis$zMax) )
lstAxis$xlab <- "glu"
lstAxis$ylab <- "BMI"
lstAxis$mainTitle <- "Pima.tr の散布図\n[row data]"
lstAxis$subTitle <- "row data"

# plot frame only
par(new=F)
plot.new()  # clear
plot( c(), type='n',
      main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
      xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim,
      xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)
grid() #グリッド線を追加

############################
# Draw figure              #
############################
# 変換前の散布図
par(new=T)
plot(
  lstPimaTrain_C1$glu, lstPimaTrain_C1$bmi,
  type='p',
  col = "red",
  pch = 1,  
  main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
  xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim, 
  xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)

par(new=T)
plot(
  lstPimaTrain_C2$glu, lstPimaTrain_C2$bmi,
  type='p',
  col = "blue",
  pch = 2,  
  main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
  xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim, 
  xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)

# 凡例の追加
legend(
  x = 0, y = 15,
  legend = c("糖尿病発症無し","糖尿病発症有り"),
  col = c("blue","red"),
  pch = c(2,1),
  text.width = 60
) 

#----------------------
# 標準化後のの散布図
#-----------------------
lstAxis$xMin <- -5
lstAxis$xMax <- 5
lstAxis$yMin <- -5
lstAxis$yMax <- 5
lstAxis$zMin <- 0
lstAxis$zMax <- 1
lstAxis$xlim = range( c(lstAxis$xMin, lstAxis$xMax) )
lstAxis$ylim = range( c(lstAxis$yMin, lstAxis$yMax) )
lstAxis$zlim = range( c(lstAxis$zMin, lstAxis$zMax) )
lstAxis$mainTitle <- "Pima.tr の散布図\n[normalized data]"
plot(
  lstNormPimaTrain_C1$glu, lstNormPimaTrain_C1$bmi,
  type='p',
  col = "red",
  pch = 1,  
  main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
  xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim, 
  xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)
grid()

par(new=T)
plot(
  lstNormPimaTrain_C2$glu, lstNormPimaTrain_C2$bmi,
  type='p',
  col = "blue",
  pch = 2,  
  main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
  xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim, 
  xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)

# 凡例の追加
legend(
  x = 0, y = 15,
  legend = c("糖尿病発症無し","糖尿病発症有り"),
  col = c("blue","red"),
  pch = c(2,1),
  text.width = 60
)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参考サイトのURLを追記しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もう解決しているかもしれませんが、目的変数が連続値で回帰分析をやる場合はtune(svm, ~~)を用いる必要があった気がします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！提案して頂いた内容で試して見ます。

Comment: 提案して頂いた内容で問題解決出来ました！ありがとうございます！